# Unable to add cookies, header already sent. Error in cron job, but not when loaded in browser

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, vbulletin

I have a cron job being run:

```
cd /home/user/public_html/index; php -f /home/user/public_html/index/stream-cron.php
```

When this file is run via the cron job the output is the following:

```
Unable to add cookies, header already sent.<br />
File: <br />
Line: 0<br />
```

However if I go to this file and run it from my browser, it works fine. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Cron job should not  use cookies, since it does not communicate with clients via HTTP

Comment: Thanks, I checked vBulletin documentation and it seems your able to stop cookies from being sent while still being able to include required files by using.

    define('NOCOOKIES', 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including outside sources, some were sending cookies. The cron job can't accept cookies thus this error was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure absolutely nothing is output before the cookie handling, no text, no 
, nothing. If possible post some code of the stream-cron.php